# three js projection problems

Tags: javascript, three.js, transform, projection

I have a very strange problem. 
I create a scene with three js and i want to project a cylinder vertex on floor of the scene and build path of it. So, when i add a cylinder, move and rotate him and then project his on a floor, the vertex, what i clone of the cylinder located at the old place, before tranforms.
Where is my mistake?

```
function drawCircle(r,seg,color,pos,mesh){

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(r,r,100,seg);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, wireframe: true, transparent: true } );
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh2.position = pos;
mesh2.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
scene.add(mesh2);

var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i=0; i < (mesh2.geometry.vertices.length/2)-1; i++)
{
    var origin = mesh2.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
    var proj   = projectOntoMesh( origin, mesh );
    lineGeometry.vertices.push( proj );
}

lineGeometry.computeLineDistances();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: color } );
var line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
scene.add(line);
scene.remove(mesh2);
//scene.remove(sphere);
}


function projectOntoMesh(point, mesh)

{


var origin = point.clone();
var direction = point.clone();
//direction.multiplyScalar(-1);
direction.y = -direction.y*25;
//direction.x = -direction.x;

//var direction = point.clone().multiplyScalar(-1);
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( origin, direction.normalize() );
var intersection = ray.intersectObject( mesh );
if ( intersection.length > 0 )
    return intersection[ 0 ].point;
else
// console.log( "No intersection?" );
    return null;
}
```

Sorry for my English...

Comment: Can you provide a full self-containing code?

Comment: do you render the scene? please show the whole code. thanks